# My program keeps jumping to the else statement straight after I give it an input. I have tried a few things but none work. (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement

Sorry the code is so messy and stuff. I'm new to C#. I've tried converting the input from a string to an int when originally it was taken straight as an int. I had a friend look at it who has a similar amount of skill to me and he couldn't find anything. I have also added and removed the Console.Clear(); commands. None of this helped. This is for a school project, so it doesn't need to be really advanced or anything, I just want a fix to this issue. I took out the content of the if and else-if statements because it isn't really relevant I don't think. Thank you!

```
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace PhysicsProject_Taylor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ///Establishes content
            Console.WriteLine(@"Welcome to the very basic Current Electricity database! \n Any bugs should be reported to Taylor
            Please note that once you have accessed data you currently need to restart the program. \n I am working on a fix to this.
            What would you like to learn about? Type the number next to the topic:
            What is a circuit? (1)
            Voltage (2)
            Current (3)
            Resistance (4)
            Ohm's Law (5)
            Series Circuit Rules and Diagrams (6)
            Parallel Circuit Rules and Diagrams (7)");

            ///Takes input and converts to Int
            Console.Write("Please input here: ");
            string ReqNum = Convert.ToString(Console.Read();
            int reqNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReqNum);

            ///If statements to display info requested.
            if (reqNum == 1)
            {
               Console.ReadLine(@"Info
                       ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                             }
            else if (reqNum == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Info
                    ");
                Console.WriteLine(@"Info
                                                                        
                                    ");
            }
            else if (reqNum == 3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(@" Info
");
                Console.WriteLine(@" Info
");

            }

            ///When an input is given this statement is jumped to immediately.
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect statement or the program has glitched. Please input a number from 1-7 else the program will not work.");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.Read returns something else than you might think. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `Console.ReadLine(@"Info                       ");` - does it even compile? Very unlikely. If you can "RUN" this exact code you pasted here, then either your IDE lies to you or you have totally overlooked the fact that your project does not build, and probably you are running some old cached version of the executable. That can happen sometimes if, for example, Visual Studio shows a popup "build error, do you want to run previous working version" and you press "yes/ok".. make 100% sure that the code you see relates to the binary you launch.

Comment: It doesn't actually look like that. I had to take the actual info out because it wasn't relevant and took up too much space. It runs fine with no apparent build errors when it is as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()`.

```
string ReqNum = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Convert.ToString(Console.Read() is missing a parenthesis, also just  do Console.Read()  no need to do extra conversion

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things could help

Try using `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()` to get your string input.

Next inside your first if statement, your code will break when you do the `Console.ReadLine(@"Info")` This should be a `Console.WriteLine(@"Info")`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have put my comments in the code, I would recommend making the following modifications to your code.

1. Fix the couple lines of code I suggested, as it will not compile as is.
2. Add an enum for better control over the user input, deal with the input as a string and parse it accordingly.

**Edit:** I noticed that you have looping menu issues as well in your code, however, I am not going to write that portion of it for you. If you need help with that portion - I would create another question on here and I would be happy to assist.

Here is the updated code (explanations embedded in the code)

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ///Establishes content
        Console.WriteLine(@"Welcome to the very basic Current Electricity database! \n Any bugs should be reported to Taylor
        Please note that once you have accessed data you currently need to restart the program. \n I am working on a fix to this.
        What would you like to learn about? Type the number next to the topic:
        What is a circuit? (1)
        Voltage (2)
        Current (3)
        Resistance (4)
        Ohm's Law (5)
        Series Circuit Rules and Diagrams (6)
        Parallel Circuit Rules and Diagrams (7)");

        ///Takes input and converts to Int
        Console.Write("Please input here: ");

        //TODO Review: Replaced string ReqNum = Convert.ToString(Console.Read(); with...
        //First, get your user's selection
        string reqNum = Console.ReadLine();
        
        //try to parse it into your enum
        //1. if the user enters a string, it will default to InvalidSelection in the out parameter
        //2. if the user enters a valid integer (1-7) it will parse into the correct enum in the out parameter
        //3. if the user enters an invalid integer (any int besides 1-7), it will parse the out parameter into an int (this is by design)
        Enum.TryParse(reqNum, out Selections userSelection);
        //You then need to validate that your out parameter is defined in your "Selections" enum, so you check if it is and move forward accordingly
        bool isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Selections), userSelection);

        if (!isDefined) {
            userSelection = Selections.InvalidSelection;
        }

        //If statements to display info requested.
        //TODO Review: I left your 'if' statements, however, I would investigate utilizing a 'switch' statement here

        if (userSelection == Selections.Circuit) {
            //TODO Review: This line was not valid
            //Console.ReadLine(@"Info
            //       ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (userSelection == Selections.Voltage) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(@"Info
                ");
            Console.WriteLine(@"Info
                                                                    
                                ");
        }
        else if (userSelection == Selections.Current) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(@" Info
            ");
            Console.WriteLine(@" Info
            ");
        }
        //This is where you handle your invalid selection...
        else {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect statement or the program has glitched. Please input a number from 1-7 else the program will not work.");
            //TODO Review: Replaced Console.Read(); with... 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    //TODO Review: I added an enum for the ease of determining valid input. If you try to parse the input into the enum equivalent, you will be able to
    //easily distinguish if the input is valid or not.
    internal enum Selections {
        InvalidSelection = 0,
        Circuit = 1,
        Voltage = 2,
        Current = 3,
        Resistance = 4,
        OhmsLaw = 5,
        SeriesCircuitRulesAndDiagrams = 6,
        ParallelCircuitRulesAndDiagrams = 7
    }
}
```